# Showing that the limit exists.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I don't understand the solution of the following question:

[image]

They are saying that when y = 0, F(x,y) = 0 and therefore it is continuous.
Does that really say that it is continuous? And how so? And also, they are saying that when y = 0, F(x,y) = 0 for all x belonging to all real numbers. But how can x be 0? Wouldn't that be 0*0/(0+0)?

And then they are saying that when y does not equal 0, x is defined everywhere. And hence this function is continuous.

I'm so confused about this question, I now it is not a hard question, but the solution does not make sense.

Thank you!

Comment: As the solution says, each variable is being held fixed - and the continuity with respect to the non-fixed variable is being assessed. 

If you fix $x=x_0\neq0$ then observe that **no matter what** $y$ is, $F(x_0,0)=0$ similarly for when $y=y_0\neq 0$ So the function is continuous in each seperate variable. 

However when you treat both $x$ and $y$ as variables, we see that it evaluates to something different at $(0,0)$ and so the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$

Comment: In other words, the only "potential" discontinuity is at the point $(0,0)$, since it is obviously continuous everywhere else. So you need to consider the **direction** in which you choose to approach $(0,0)$. The question touches on the fact that it is not sufficient enough to conclude that a function is continuous just because it is for each individual variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=F(x,0)$.  Then, from the definition of $F(x,y)$ given in the OP we can write

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&,x\ne 0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$

Inasmuch as $f(x)\equiv 0$ for all $x$, it is a continuous function.

Similarly, let $g(y)=F(0,y)$.  Then, from the definition of $F(x,y)$ given in the OP we can write

> $$g(y)=\begin{cases}0&,y\ne 0\\\\0&,y=0\end{cases}$$

Inasmuch as $g(y)\equiv 0$ for all $y$, it is a continuous function.

However, the function $h(x)=F(x,x)$ is given by

> $$h(x)=\begin{cases}\frac12&,x\ne=0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$

is evidently discontinuous at $x=0$.

> We conclude that $F(x,y)$ cannot be continuous due to the discontinuity at the origin.

---

**NOTE:**

To make all of the preceding more concise, we simply note that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}F(x,y)$ fails to exist (and hence $F(x,y)$ cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$) since on the path $x=t$, $y=0$ we have

$$\lim_{t\to 0}F(t,0)=0$$

while on the path $x=y=t$ we have

$$\lim_{t\to 0}F(t,t)=\frac12$$

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very clear :) But I have just a quick question, so despite all x values, f(x) is always  0 and therefore it is continuous?

Comment: I'm just having a hard time imagining the plot of this function. It's a 3-D graph with x, y, and z axis. The y values will always be 0, right? Then, for all x values and corresponding z values, y will always be 0? Then, when x = 0, it will be y will still be 0? I might have confused you, but is this a right logic?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  To answer your question, the function $f$ is identically $0$ and thus continuous.  -Mark

Comment: Oh never mind, thank you for the help!

Comment: Jack, you're really quite welcome.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

At that point in the argument, they are specifically making no claim about continuity across $y$ values; only when moving across $x$ at any *constant* $y$.

They are asserting that $F(x\times 0)$ is continuous across all $x$, *and* that $F(x\times c)$ is continuous across all $x$ for non-zero $c$.   Therefore $F(x\times c)$ is continuous across all $x$ for an arbitrary constant $c$, zero or otherwise.

---

Also notice that the definition of $F$ is a piecewise function.   It is $0$ when *both* $x$ and $y$ are zero and *otherwise* it is $xy/(x^2+y^2)$.

Thus $F(x\times 0)=\begin{cases} 0 &:& x\times 0=0\times 0 \\ 0(x/(x^2+0^2)) &:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\~=~ 0$

---

They then show the same result for keep in $x$ constant.   However, a different result arises on the part of $x=y$, as there is a discontinuity in 
$$F(x\times x) = \begin{cases}0 & : & x=0\\ \tfrac 12 & :& x\neq 0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The book is trying to show that

$$g(x) := \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}1_{\{0\}}(x)$$ is continuous (on $\mathbb R$)

Regardless of the value of y.

$y$ here is treated as constant, but its value leads to very different $g(x)$'s. We have to show that in the different $g(x)$'s, we have a continuous (on R) function.

---

It's like if I asked you if this is continuous:

$$h(x) = x^21_{(0,\infty)}(x) + b1_{\{0\}}(x) + -x1_{(-\infty,0)}(x)$$

Case 1: $b=0$

Then $h(x)$ is continuous

Case 2: $b \ne 0$

Then $h(x)$ is not continuous

Since $h(x)$ is not continuous (on R) in each case ie regardless of the value of b, it is not continuous (on R).

---

Going back:

Case 1: $y=0$

Then $g(x) \equiv 0$.

Here, g is constant, and constant functions are continuous
(on R).

Case 2: $y \ne 0$

Then $g(x) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is defined on all $\mathbb R$*

Here, g is a rational function.

In single variable calculus, we are given that rational functions are continuous wherever they are defined (or some classes prove it. Whatever).

Since $g(x)$ is a rational function defined on $\mathbb R$, $g(x)$ is continuous (on $\mathbb R$).

---

*Note that if $y$ can be $0$, then this is not true.

$\frac{1}{x^2+b}$ isn't defined on $\mathbb R$ if $b \le 0$ because we may have $x=\pm \sqrt{b}$ but is defined on all $\mathbb R$ if $b>0$ since the denominator will never be zero.

Thus, $\frac{1}{x^2+b}$ is not continuous on $\mathbb R$ if $b \le 0$ because it is not defined on $\mathbb R$. However, $\frac{1}{x^2+b}$ is continuous on wherever it is defined for any $b$.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about your two cases. Your conclude that g(x) is continuous only because of case 2? Does case 1 help to prove that? Because they are totally opposite, y = 0 and and when y ≠ 0

Comment: @Jack ah good question. I think g is continuous (on R) if it is continuous (on R)  in all cases ie regardless of the value of y. Case 1: g is continuous (on R). Case 2: g is continuous (on R). Therefore, g is continuous (on R).

Comment: @Jack edited answer